# Customize Shell Prompt Oh-my-zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Consider the following screenshot

[image]

I'm using oh-my-zsh for shell customization. But due to the longer paths , I am unable to write longer linux commands. I want to change the prompt that only showing me the current directly keeping everything to the same.

> Theme
> ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerlevel9k has been discontinued, see the note at the top of https://github.com/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k. It's highly recommended to upgrade to Powerlevel10k.

Here's how to upgrade:

1. Add powerlevel10k to the list of Oh My Zsh themes.

```bsh
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/themes/powerlevel10k
```

2. Replace `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"` with `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"` in `~/.zshrc`.

```bsh
sed -i.bak 's/powerlevel9k/powerlevel10k/g' ~/.zshrc
```

3. Restart Zsh.

```bsh
exec zsh
```

Once you restart Zsh, prompt configuration wizard should start automatically. If it doesn't, type `p10k configure`. At some point the wizard will ask whether you want a one-line or a two-line prompt. The two-line version gives you a lot more room for typing commands, so you'll want to choose that. Two-line prompt usually wastes half of terminal's vertical space but with Powerlevel10k you have an option to enable Transient Prompt to avoid this downside.

In addition, you might want to add these lines to `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
# My Windows home directory.
hash -d w=/mnt/c/Users/Pawar
```

This establishes bidirectional mapping between `~w` and `/mnt/c/Users/Pawar`. Instead of `/mnt/c/Users/Pawar/Downloads` prompt will display `~w/Downloads`. You can type `cd ~w/Downloads` instead of `cd /mnt/c/Users/Pawar/Downloads`, etc. Tab-completion understand this mapping, too. So `cd ~w/`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will work.

Comment: ok I shall upgrade right away

Comment: @AashishPawar FYI: I've added a recommendation at the bottom of my answer to define a named directory. It'll make working in WSL more pleasant.

Comment: it says zsh: command not found p10k

Comment: I got the following error when cloned the git repo =>  /home/aashish/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:source:125: no such file or directory: /home/aashish/.oh-my-zsh/themes/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

Comment: These errors mean that either you haven't cloned powerlevel10k or you have cloned it to a wrong directory. Run this command: `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git /home/aashish/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k && exec zsh`

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem